# prove that function is injective

Tags: functions

I am stuck at this. I can't prove this is injective.

I know the definition is $f(x)=f(y) \Rightarrow x=y$

The function:

$$f(x) := x \cdot \ln(3 + x) $$

This is what I got until now:

$$x \ln(3+x)=y \ln(3+y)$$

How can I prove that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal that you can't prove the injectivity since it's not injective. For example $f(-2)=f(0).$